# Alinhamento CSS Webmail

Tags: html, css, email

Estou com dificuldades para alinhar o texto de um tag `<span>`, utilizo o `margin-left` no css e ele funciona porém só da a margem na primeira linha

```html
<tr bgcolor="#fff">
  <td style="padding:0px 40px 6px 40px;margin:0; text-align: left; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;">
    <span style="margin-left: 20px !important; mso-line-height-rule: 1.6; line-height:1.6; font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 16px">
      INTIMAÇÃO DE ADVOGADOS RELAÇÃO Nº 0436/2018 JUÍZO DE DIREITO DA VARA DO ÚNICO OFÍCIO DE SÃO JOSÉ DA TAPERA EDITAL DE INTIMAÇÃO DE ADVOGADOS ADV: LUIZ JOSÉ MALTA GAIA FERREIRA (OAB 3404/AL), ADV:
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Segue a print para melhorar o entendimento.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não use `margin` no `span` use `padding` na `td`

```html
<table>
    <tr bgcolor="#fff">
            <td style="text-align: left; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px; padding: 0 20px;">
              <span style=" mso-line-height-rule: 1.6; line-height:1.6; font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 16px">
                INTIMAÇÃO DE ADVOGADOS RELAÇÃO Nº 0436/2018 JUÍZO DE DIREITO DA VARA DO ÚNICO OFÍCIO DE SÃO JOSÉ DA TAPERA EDITAL DE INTIMAÇÃO DE ADVOGADOS ADV: LUIZ JOSÉ MALTA GAIA FERREIRA (OAB 3404/AL), ADV:
              </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

O ideal seria utilizar `div`, ao invés de `span`. Mas pode resolver adicionando o atributo `display: inline-block;` na sua tag `span`:

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr bgcolor="#fff">
          <td style="padding:0px 40px 6px 40px;margin:0; text-align: left; margin-left: 20px; margin-right: 20px;">
            <span style="display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px !important; mso-line-height-rule: 1.6; line-height:1.6; font-family: Trebuchet MS; font-size: 16px">
              INTIMAÇÃO DE ADVOGADOS RELAÇÃO Nº 0436/2018 JUÍZO DE DIREITO DA VARA DO ÚNICO OFÍCIO DE SÃO JOSÉ DA TAPERA EDITAL DE INTIMAÇÃO DE ADVOGADOS ADV: LUIZ JOSÉ MALTA GAIA FERREIRA (OAB 3404/AL), ADV:
            </span>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Leitura recomendada: [HTML - span](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp)